# How to inherit returnPressed() from QLineEdit to QPlainTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

meetis is my src,

```
class CodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit, QLineEdit):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QPlainTextEdit.__init__(self, parent)
    QLineEdit.__init__(self, parent)
    self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)
    self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
    self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
    self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
    self.returnPressed.connect(self.IndentCall)
    self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)


@pyqtSlot(str, QPlainTextEdit)
def IndentCall(self):
    if self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText().endswith(':\n'):
        self.ui.textEdit.insertPlainText('    ')
```

Error that i get is,

```
File "D:\Python-Projects\CodeEditor\codeeditor.py", line 26, in __init__
self.returnPressed.connect(self.IndentCall)
TypeError: decorated slot has no signature compatible with returnPressed()
```

I don't want to create a event handler, all i want is to simply inherit a function into another Widget.
Fellow programmer please help me with this error, if possible provide and example.

!! Thanks In Advance !!

Comment: @eyllanesc Here i tried and got some bugs but i have updated the question!

Comment: @eyllanesc I went though those two alike links, but I don't want to create a event handler, all i want is to simply inherit a function into another Widget.

Comment: You can not in PyQt, you are going down a path that will lead you to a ravine of many problems.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok Got it! So i will go the other way,
BTW Thanks